# Помогите создать функцию для подсчёта процентов от введенного числа

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, словари

```
colors = {1 : {'Желтый': 3.1, 'Красный': 96.9},
       2 : {'Желтый': 12.5, 'Черный': 87.5},
       3 : {'Синий': 50.0, 'Черный': 50.0}}

n = int(input("Какой номер цвета? :"))
print()
print('Номер цвета:', n, 'C,U')
new_color = {}

for key in colors[n]:
    print(key + ':', colors[n][key], '%')
print()
for s in colors.values():
   new_color.update(colors[n])

x = float(input("Количество грамм краски?:"))
def procent(**new_color):
    for key in new_color:
        print(key, "->", new_color[key])
procent(**new_color)
```

```
Какой номер цвета? :3

Номер цвета: 3 C,U
Синий: 50.0 %
Черный: 50.0 %

Количество грамм краски?:345
Синий -> 50.0
Черный -> 50.0
```

Вместо `Синий -> 50.0` и `Черный -> 50.0` должно быть `Синий -> 172.5` и `Черный -> 172.5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот верный вариант:

```
colors = {1 : {'Желтый': 3.1, 'Красный': 96.9},
       2 : {'Желтый': 12.5, 'Черный': 87.5},
       3 : {'Синий': 50.0, 'Черный': 50.0}}

n = int(input("Какой номер цвета? :"))
print()
print('Номер цвета:', n, 'C,U')
new_color = {}

for key in colors[n]:
    print(key + ':', colors[n][key], '%')
print()
for s in colors.values():
   new_color.update(colors[n])

x = float(input("Количество грамм краски?:"))
def procent(**new_color):
    for key in new_color:
        print(key, "->", round(x * (new_color[key] / 100), 2)) # находим процент от числа
procent(**new_color)
```

Comment: round функцию на 2 нужно добавить а то сильно длинный ответ получается

Comment: @Bogdangusakov Ну, для округления можно)

Comment: а можно ещё исключения прописать?

Comment: @Bogdan gusakov в каком смысле исключения?

Comment: Всё  разобрался сделал сам

Answer (score 1):

кажется в исходном коде есть лишние строки.
так вроде должно сработать:

```
colors = {1 : {'Желтый': 3.1, 'Красный': 96.9},
          2 : {'Желтый': 12.5, 'Черный': 87.5},
          3 : {'Синий': 50.0, 'Черный': 50.0}}

n = int(input("Какой номер цвета? :"))
print()
print('Номер цвета:', n, 'C,U')
x = float(input("Количество грамм краски?:"))
print('\n'.join(f'{k} -> {round(v*x/100,2)}' for k,v in colors[n].items()))

#
Синий -> 172.5
Черный -> 172.5
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь

Comment: а исключения можно прописать ещё?